# What is a ConsensusHook?

Tags: parachain, parachain-system, async-backing

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/769bdd3ff33a291cbc70a800a3830638467e42a2/cumulus/pallets/parachain-system/src/consensus_hook.rs#L61

> The definition of a [`ConsensusHook`] trait for consensus logic to manage the backlog
> of parachain blocks ready to submit to the relay chain, as well as some basic implementations.

We see this new trait appear on `cumulus-pallet-parachain-system` under feature `"parameterized-consensus-hook"` and I am looking for an ELI5 explanation. More specifically, an explainer of `segments` that's quoted in the code comments.

How do I determine to add this new code (`ConsensusHook`) to my parachain `cumulus-pallet-parachain-system::Config`?